# TSQL Linked Server: How to restore a database to a link server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am currently stuck on this part, I want to restore a database from a backup file to a different SQL Server/instance.

The other server has been created as a linked server, so there is a link between the two servers.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is my code that I used to restore to the local server:

```
SET @RestoreDatabase = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = ''' + @DatabaseName + ''')
                        BEGIN
                            RESTORE DATABASE [' + @DatabaseName + '] FROM  DISK = ''' + @BackupDest + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N''Default'' TO ''' + @mdf + ''',  MOVE N''Default_log'' TO ''' + @ldf + ''',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
                        END
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            PRINT ''' + @DatabaseName + ' Already exist.''
                        END'
EXECUTE (@RestoreDatabase)
```

Comment: You need to use `EXECUTE (...) AT`: [Using EXECUTE with AT linked_server_name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#g-using-execute-with-at-linked_server_name)

Comment: On a different note `'[' + @DatabaseName + ']'` isn't injection safe. Use `'...' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + '...'`. If you can guarentee that `@mdf` and `@BackupDest` are going to be 128 characters or less, then similarly use `QUOTENAME(@mdf,'''')`, however, if not ensure you use `REPLACE(@mdf,'''','''''')` to escape any single quotes in the string.

Comment: Hi Larnu, thank you I just found it and tried it and it seems like it worked, but my question is, if I do another restore on that same day, for example the database is full, and the new restore's mdf and ldf location and file name is the same, is that going to cause an issue ?

Comment: According to your code above, if the database already exists on the instance, it'll `PRINT` the string `{Database}  Already exist.`

Comment: I know, but I want to add a check in my code if the archive database reaches a certain amount of space then a new database will be restored with the default.bak (default database backup) I just wanted to know if it would cause issues if the new database also directs to the same mdf and ldf. I am going to create a check to generate different database names for example: ARC_Archive_200513 and the next one on the same day would be ARC_Archive_100513_1

Comment: Also thank you for telling me about the way I declare my code that it won't be injection safe. That is very good to know. I will try your method. Thank you so much